# Is there a way to dynamically change the name of the class being autoloaded?

Tags: php, autoloader

For instance, say I have the following code.

```
$foo = new bar();
```

And an autoloader like this.

```
function autoload($class_name) {
    $class_file_name = str_replace('_', '/', $class_name) . '.php';
    if (file_exists($class_file_name)) {
        include($class_file_name);
    }
}
```

But the class I really want to load is in the folder 'foo/bar.php', and the real class name is actually foo_bar. Is there a way to dynamically change the name of the class being autoloaded? For instance, something like this?

```
function autoload(&$class_name) {
    $class_name = 'foo_' . $class_name;
    $class_file_name = str_replace('_', '/', $class_name) . '.php';
    if (file_exists($class_file_name)) {
        include($class_file_name);
    }
}
```

I know if something like this is possible, it is not exactly best practice, but I would still like to know if it is.

Comment: This sounds like something that would result in code that's very confusing to read

Comment: The "(PHP)" you keep adding at the end of your question titles is redundant. Tags are a separate feature of SO.

Comment: If your file name is "foo/bar.php" and your class name is "foo_bar", then calling `new bar()` is going to require that the class named "bar" exist, not the class named "foo_bar".  This request seems kind of insane.  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: +1 for the ampersand in `function autoload(&$class_name)` though. That's awesome =)

Comment: @Charles Hey, I said that! =p

Comment: @ Tomalak Geret'kal sorry to have annoyed you with my (PHP)s. I will reframe in the future.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen actually it's meant to make the code easier to read despite the folder structure.

Comment: I fell like this is something that should be solved somewhere else. You may find a hack. However, **why would you call for a `new bar`  if you want a `foo_bar`**? Another programmer looking at your code will have trouble finding where `foo_bar` is defined. Keep the magic to the minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use [class_alias](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php), this way:

- PHP requires class X
- You want load class Y instead.
- You create an alias X for class Y, so X will behave like Y.

E.g.:

```
function autoload($class_name) {
    $real_class_name = 'foo_' . $class_name;
    $class_file_name = str_replace('_', '/', $real_class_name) . '.php';
    if (file_exists($class_file_name)) {
        include($class_file_name);
        class_alias($real_class_name, $class_name);
    }
}
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Pretty cool. Never knew this function existed. This may be what I am looking for.

Comment: That's sick! (In a very kewl way!) But even if this enables you to do what you want: beware. See Matti Virkkunen's comment (it has 6 votes for a reason)

Comment: The main drawback I see is: you must be aware that the two class names (real and alias) are loaded in your namespace; so try to avoid name conflicts. ;)

Answer (score 4):

No. You could load a different file. You could load no file. You could load several files. But after autoloading, PHP expects the class to exist like it was called.

If you call a class X, you can't magically give PHP class Y.

Maybe it's enough to set up the filesystem like that, but still keep literal class names?

**PS**
I've wanted this for a while too. When I didn't have access to namespaces yet. Now that I do, all my problems are solved =) If you do have access to namespaces, you should 'study' [PSR-0](http://groups.google.com/group/php-standards/web/psr-0-final-proposal).

Comment: +1 for PSR-0.  It's worth noting that PSR-0 doesn't require namespaces to operate, it simply works with them.  There won't be a problem using the example code in PHP 5.2.

Comment: Fair enough. I never used it before namespaces, but I guess you're right. These days, I never have `_` in my class names anymore, so I guess you have a point.

Comment: Yes, in the real code I am using a PSR-0 autoloader. This was just an example to simplify the question. The problem is that I do not want to have to prefix every class in the library folder with library_ or library\ for instance.

Comment: Edit queue if full, here is new PSR-0 link: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/